# Ethereum - Missing semi-colon whilst using script from Udemy

Tags: go-ethereum

I am trying to learn how to create contracts using a course in Udemy that my work provides. I am following the steps 1 by 1 but am receiving the following error. Any help would be appreciated
**Error:**

```
Expected token Semicolon got 'eth_compileSolidity'
        Function TCoin(int256 initialSupply) {
                  ^
```

**Code:**

```
pragma solidity 0.4.8;
contract TCoin{
        mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;

        Function TCoin(int256 initialSupply) {
          //balanceOf[Msg.sender] = initialSupply;
        }

        Function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value){
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be `function`, not `Function`.

Answer (score 2):

As mafrasi2 pointed out, the proper keyword is `function`
If you're learning from a course that has as blatant an error as that, I would probably stop using that as a resource. I'm pretty sure I know the one you're talking about, and there's *loads* of other resources out there that are better, and free.

Here's a few of them:

https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev

https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity

https://github.com/DigixGlobal/solidity-collections-library

https://github.com/androlo/standard-contracts

https://github.com/pirapira/awesome-ethereum-virtual-machine

http://solidity.readthedocs.io/

Comment: Indeed, not to mention the course is apparently for solidity 0.4.8 (I think we're around 0.4.20 now), so there will be key functionality that didn't even exist back in 0.4.8.

Comment: thank you very much. Indeed that solved my errors and now I will unenrol from that course and check the ones Hextet provided! Cheers all!